Azure builds from GitHub fork don't work if require comment enabled
We have a GitHub test repository setup, and have successfully integrated this with a paid pipeline on Azure. We can creating a PR as owner and that will build on Azure, and when we get a PR from an external user, that also builds fine with these settings in our Pipeline Trigger settings:

azure-pipeline.yml trigger:
trigger:

main

However, when we enable "Require a team member's comment before building a pull request" on the Project pipeline settings, builds stop working. Our understanding is that a comment from either a team member or repository owner, on the Conversations tab of the PR in question, should trigger a build. But it doesn't appear to do anything.
Our settings:
Under Azure Organization Settings:

Under Azure Project Settings:

Under Azure Pipeline Settings:

Are we missing a setting somewhere, or perhaps not making the comment correctly or in the correct place?

The behavior is correct acutally. After you enable Require a team member's comment before building a pull request, the pull request validation build won’t be triggered automatically, unless Only on pull requests from non-team members is selected and the PR is made by a team member.
If you enable On all pull requests, you need to use a team member account to review the pull request and triggers the build with a comment like /AzurePipelines run or /AzurePipelines run <pipeline-name>.
Please check the Comment triggers doc for the details:

In addition, if you would like to check the comment trigger, please enable Override the YAML pull request trigger from here as the setting is from the Triggers page.
Hope it helps!

Aha! Thank you. It is the Comment Triggers documents I missed reading, and using /AzurePipelines run does exactly what we want.

You are welcome! Glad to know it helps! Happy day!
